# admin or logged in user privileges

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any way I can allow administrative privileges or logged in users to only view a certain page, eg: list of products available, on my website? I know session can be used in php, but other than that is there any other way?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sessions are built for producing the results what you need. Solutions other then sessions may be if conditions but you will need to repeat things over and over again.

Comment: Is your website build on any framework?

Comment: Get good example by searching custom authorization in php

Comment: you should merge to a CMS like wordpress !